# Google Map Marker Tooltip

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How do I get the default tooltip `title: 'Testing'` of each marker to update via the XML data that I am parsing down in the script from this?

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    title: 'Testing',
    icon: 'images/test.png' ,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });
```

Loading XML (want to pull from `var name`):

```
downloadUrl("data.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the title text of a marker with the `setTitle()` method:

```
marker.setTitle(name);
```

Comment: If I do marker.setTitle(name); or even just title: name,  The data gets returned for the entire <marker> data set, not just the name field.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "the entire <amrker> data set".